# Can't display user data from Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application was able to load data from Firebase's database but now I'm not able to display it. I'm assuming this has to do with an Firebase update. I was able to access the data by calling .child("users").child((currentUser?.uid)!).child("userDetails") with my currentUser being Auth.auth().currentUser. Has the method changed? How can an iOS application read the data from Firebase?

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if currentUser == nil {
        self.showMessage(messageToDisplay: "Could not read user details")
        return
    }

    print("User id = \(String(describing: currentUser?.uid))")
    print("User email \(String(describing: currentUser?.email))")
    print("Is email verified \(String(describing: currentUser?.isEmailVerified))")

    var databaseReference:DatabaseReference!
    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    databaseReference.child("users").child((currentUser?.uid)!).child("userDetails").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

        let userDetailsData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let firstName = userDetailsData?["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
        let lastName = userDetailsData?["lastName"] as? String ?? ""

        self.fullNameLabel.text = self.fullNameLabel.text! + " " + firstName + " " + lastName
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

Listener at /users/(userID omitted)/userDetails failed: permission_denied
TIC TCP Conn Failed [9:0x604000169e40]: 1:61 Err(61)
HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
Task  finished with error - code: -1004
Encounter network error. Code, error: -1004, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."

Comment: Check your firebase rules to make sure that it allows .read at 'users' node

Comment: "users": {
     "$uid":{
        ".read":"auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }

Answer (score 0):

By default, the database in a Firebase project is only accessible by authenticated users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

So to display user data you either need to change the rules to allow unauthenticated users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Or authenticate users before trying to access user data:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  if error == nil {
    // Success!
  } else {
    // Sign in failed
  }  
}
```